# Arduino: Using Serial.read() without blinking on LED matrix

Tags: arduino, serial-port, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am using esp8266 with Arduino framework to drive a LED matrix display and some sensors. The problem I encountered is as follows: when I want to read data from CO2 sensor (mhz-19b) I have to do so by sending a command via serial and then read the answer it gives me. This of course takes some time and causes a delay in my code which means the LED matrix display stops refreshing and goes dark for a short but noticable amount of time.
I have a smiliar problem with reading data from DHT22 temperature and humidity sensor (reading data takes some time and causes a delay in code).

Is there anyway I could solve this? Perhaps with some kind of pseudo-multithreading (if that even exists). Also would using esp32 (which is dual core) instead of esp8266 help?

Comment: *"Perhaps with some kind of pseudo-multithreading"* -- Close, it's called multitasking programming which is what an OS uses with multiple processes. Apparently your code busy waits (i.e. hogs the CPU) when reading data from the UART. Instead of polling use an interrupt scheme, and then the CPU could be doing something else like updating the LED matrix display. A dual core is not going to help unless you know how to split your one program into two, i.e. one for each core, and coordinate them.   See https://www.electronicshub.org/arduino-multitasking-tutorial/

Comment: It depends on how you write the serial code.  Generally the output isn't going to cause this problem.  It's just going into a buffer.  It's the receive code that can cause problems.  If you read one byte at a time in a non-blocking fashion and let the loop function be the only loop involved then you can keep up with the matrix at the same time.  If you insist on sitting in a while loop reading until the whole buffer is done then you'll have issues.

Comment: For better help, post your code.